# Switched Hosts from Inmotion to Linode but Redirect Still occurring

Tags: hosting, redirect, linode

We recently switched servers from inmotion hosting to linode and everything is going well except when you go to www.oursite.com it redirects to www.oursite.com/zen which was behavior that was set up on the old inmotion server.

This website is 100% new code so there is no way the redirect is in the code.

We're trying to get our hands on the old inmotion hosting login info to shut off the redirect but shouldn't that old account have no impact on the new server?

I checked with GoDaddy where the domain was purchased and the redirect isn't occurring there.

The switch was done 24 hours ago so I don't think it's a propagation issue.

Thanks for any advice you can give us.

Answer (score 1):

> there is no way the redirect is in the code.
>   but shouldn't that old account have no impact on the new server?
>   I checked with GoDaddy and the redirect isn't occurring there.
>   The switch was done 24 hours ago so I don't think it's a propagation issue.

Well... you're not going to solve it by guesswork, it's happening *somewhere* along the way.

- ping www.oursite.com
- Find which IP address it resolves to, check it is the new Linode server IP. If not, what is it pointing to and why?
- Install something like the TamperData addin for Firefox, open it and browse to the site. It will show you what is happening in the HTTP connection, and if there is a redirect being sent to your browser, when it happens. e.g. does it happen first, or after loading /index.php or after loading some other part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

There was no redirect going on.   Apparently if you go to a site that does a redirect, Chrome caches it and until you clear your cache through the options (CTRL + F5 didn't work), it'll continue doing it even if the site is hosted on a new IP.

I figured it out because FF and IE didn't do the redirect.